# How to check a single column of a query with multiple columns of subquery?

Tags: java, sqlite

I'm trying to compare if a single column of my table equals to what the subquery returns in multiple columns. I want to be able to return rows if table1.id is equal to either one of table2.first or table2.second. What would be the valid syntax to do it?

I've tried what's below ,but it's not valid syntax as I get "Result: sub-select returns 2 columns - expected 1."

`SELECT table1.id, table1.attr1, table1.attr2 FROM table1 WHERE table1.id IN (SELECT table2.first, table2.second FROM table2 WHERE type != "..." AND type != "someType")`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you intend something like this:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.attr1,
    t1.attr2
FROM table1 t1
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.first = t1.id AND type <> 'someType') OR
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.second = t1.id AND type <> 'someType');
```

Each `EXISTS` clause checks for a possible match of a `table1.id` value against a `table2` column.

Comment: Is this faster than just using OR between 2 IN statements?

Comment: @Muhammed That depends on how SQLite optimizes `WHERE IN`.  Most likely, my answer would not be _slower_ than using `WHERE IN`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need subquery if you want to select from `t1` only if the conditions match. Try below query:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.attr1,
    t1.attr2
FROM table1 t1 , table2 t2
WHERE
    (t1.id = t2.first OR t1.id = t2.second)
    AND t2.type not in ('someType' , "...");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with an INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id, t1.attr1, t1.attr2 
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t2.first = t1.id OR t2.second = t1.id
WHERE t2.type <> "..." AND t2.type <> "someType"
```

The ON clause can be written as well like:

```
ON t1.id IN (t2.first, t2.second)
```

I used `DISTINCT` in case `table1.id` could match multiple rows in `table2`.